# How to print a PDF to something other than the default printer

Tags: c#, winforms

I used this code to print a pdf file from acrobat reader.

```
private void SendToPrinter()
{
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.Verb = "print";
    info.FileName = @"c:\output.pdf";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();

    p.WaitForInputIdle();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
        p.Kill();
}
```

However, it prints through default printer.

How can I select the printer to send it to? default.

I have tried with a property for ex: info.Arguments, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You got the question's title wrong (filter instead of printer).

Answer (score 3):

Use the /t command line argument to force adobe to use a specific printer:

```
AcroRd32.exe /t path "printername" "drivername" "portname"
```

See the PDF developer FAQ for more info:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/intro_to_sdk/DeveloperFAQ.pdf

Answer (score 1):

How about using the "printto" [verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verbs.aspx)? pasing `"\\\server\printer"` for `info.Arguments`

Comment: Close, but the complete answer is shown at the following SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5432909/964043