# How to print only 1 copy of document when using "Process" in c#

Tags: c#, printing, processstartinfo

I am trying to print a pdf in a c# console application, by starting a process.
Instead of printing only 1 copy of the document it prints multiple copies (3, 4, 5 or 6 unpredictable). This is my code...

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Verb = "PrintTo",
        Arguments = printerName,
        FileName = filePath
    }
};
p.Start();
```

Please can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is all the code? What if you print by using the `PrintDialog`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432909/815938)? Is only 1 copy is set in the print dialog?

Comment: @kennyzx I do not have a print dialogue. I want it to print automatically without the user having to click anything.

Comment: yes, I understand...But I can only think of the cause of this to be some incorrect settings of the printer, which can be examined in the print dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this code.

```
 private void SendToPrinter(string prepDok)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = prepDok;
        info.CreateNoWindow = false;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog pd = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        p.Start();
        p.CloseMainWindow();

        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        if (!p.WaitForExit(5000))
        {
            if (!p.HasExited)
            {
                p.Kill();
            }
        }

    }
```

This will set the number of copies to one and print dialog won't be shown.